# Load time is to high for our website

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

The load time of my website  is too high, I have a lot of configurable products and when disabled the configurable swatches there is no change. I tried a lot of searches but I can't solve my issue!

We have a lot of queries when I checked: 7K references to catalog_category_entity I don't know How can I solve the problem of categories queries!!

Can you help us to solve this issue?

Comment: Use https://www.webpagetest.org/ test your url, improve possible manner.

Comment: Test your website on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ and try to improve it based on its report.

Comment: I tried both of them and I update d alot of things but some issues I can't do them

Comment: The category pages are too slow

Comment: please post logs, profiler, shop setup, server specs, etc... nobody knows it, how we can help you????